# AngularJS HTML data object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I have an attribute with it's data being an object? I want to set the data to two indices:

```
<div ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts">
    <div ng-repeat="tasks in shift" data-drag="{'taskIndex' : $index, 'shiftIndex' : $parent.$index}"></div>
</div>
```

I basically want to set `data-drag` to contain both the `$index` and `$parent.$index`. The code above doesn't work!

Thanks

EDIT

So the problem is not the syntax above. It comes from this other line that I have:

```
 // Grab the object data
 var dragData = "";
 scope.$watch(attrs.drag, function (newValue) {
      dragData = newValue;
 });
```

The `$watch` returns this error:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

If I simply assign `data-drag="$index"` then, it is all fine. Why is it that I cannot pass an object?

Why?

Comment: How doesn't the code work? What are you trying to do with the indexes in data-drag?

Comment: Can you post a plunker and indicate which part of your code doesn't work.

Comment: Using `data-drag="{'taskIndex' : $index, 'shiftIndex' : $parent.$index}"` returns an error! The syntax is wrong ... It says `$digest()` aborted after trying for 10 times.

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce any of the problems you're facing with the code you've provided. Can you either post your own Plunk/Fiddle or update this one to better demonstrate your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/762BM/1/

Comment: Wow thank you! My problem was that I was not including the `{{` around `$index`! The problem is fixed! If you post yours as a reply, I can vote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bind `$index` and `$parent.$index`, you need to wrap them in curly braces inside of your `data-drag` attribute definition:

```
<div ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts">
    <div ng-repeat="tasks in shift" data-drag="{'taskIndex' : {{$index}}, 'shiftIndex' : {{$parent.$index}}}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `data-drag` is but you can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to create an object with the inner and outer index in it.

```
<div ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts" ng-init="shiftIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="tasks in shift" 
        ng-init="myVar = {taskIndex: $index, shiftIndex: shiftIndex}" 
        data-drag="myVar">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6DuU9/

Comment: Problem is that `schedule.shifts` and `shifts.tasks` dynamically change and therefore `$index` and `$parent.$index` change as well. If I use `ng-init` I then need to reassign `myVar` everytime the arrays change. I would rather if I could pass the indices directly to `data-drag`